Is a declarator considered a 'superset' of an identifier in 'C'?
I was reading the C standard (C17) and I still don't get what is the difference between a declarator and an identifier , my guess is that and identifier is just that, the 'ID', the name/alias for a 'C object' but a declarator is 'something more than just a name'
I mean:
//x is the identifier and x[5] is the declarator (direct declarator)
int x[5]; 

//y is the identifier and y[] is the declarator (direct declarator)
char y[]="Hello there"; 

//p is the identifier and *p is the declarator ('simple' declarator)
float *p; 

//foo is the identifier and 'foo(intzx, float zy)' is the declarator
void foo(int zx, float zy); 

But I don't know if this is correct, or I need to introduce the concept of 'full declarator'?

If you read the C standard (e.g. C11 §6.7.6 Declarators), you'll see that a declarator can be as simple as an identifier, but can be very complex:

declarator:
        pointeropt direct-declarator
direct-declarator:
        identifier
        ( declarator )
        direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
        direct-declarator [ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
        direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
        direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt * ]
        direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
        direct-declarator ( identifier-listopt )
pointer:
        * type-qualifier-listopt
        * type-qualifier-listopt pointer
type-qualifier-list:
        type-qualifier
        type-qualifier-list type-qualifier
parameter-type-list:
        parameter-list
        parameter-list , ...
parameter-list:
        parameter-declaration
        parameter-list , parameter-declaration
parameter-declaration:
        declaration-specifiers declarator
        declaration-specifiers abstract-declaratoropt
identifier-list:
        identifier
        identifier-list , identifier

So, there are two declarators in this line of code:
int i, *(*function)(int, int);

One is i, a simple identifier.
The other identifies function as a pointer to a function which takes two int arguments and returns a pointer to an int.  And that's by no means the most complex possible declarator.

It's not a superset, they are simply 2 different syntax items for different purposes. A declarator may contain identifiers, but that's all they have in common.
Declarator is a syntax item appearing in the many forms of declarations allowed by the language, which very likely contains an identifier somewhere at the bottom of the syntax, as shown in the answer by @Jonathan Leffler.
But an identifier is one of the most basic syntax items in the language, as seen in 6.4, where the C language can be said to contain one of the following items:

token:
keyword
identifier
constant
string-literal
punctuator

The formal definition can be found in 6.4.2:

An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and
uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as
described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct. There is no specific limit on the
maximum length of an identifier.

This in turn could be a variable ("object"), a function, an enumeration constant, a macro name etc etc. Which in turn may appear in all manner of contexts: operations, function calls, declarations etc etc.
